# Get blob contents from last modified folder in Azure container via Azure logic apps

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps

I have an Azure logic app that's getting blob contents from my Azure storage account on a regular basis. However, my blobs are getting stored in sub-directories.
Eg. MyContainer > Invoice > 20200101 > Invoice1.csv

Every month my 3rd sub-directory that is '20200101' will change to '20200201', '20200301' so & so forth.
I need my Logic app to return the blob contents of the latest folder that gets created in my container.
Any advice regarding this?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this requirement, please refer to my logic app below:

**1.** List all of the folders under `/mycontainer/Invoice/`.
[image]

**2.** Initialize two variables in type of Integer, one named `maxNum` and the other named `numberFormatOfName`.
[image]

**3.** Use "For each" to loop the `value` from "List blobs" above. In "For each" loop, first set `numberFormatOfName` with expression `int(replace(items('For_each')?['Name'], '/', ''))`. Then add a "If" condition to judge if `numberFormatOfName` greater than `maxNum`. If true, set the value of `maxNum` with `numberFormatOfName`.
[image]

**4.** After the "For each" loop, use another "List blobs" to list all of the blobs in latest(max number) folder. The expression in below screenshot is `string(variables('maxNum'))`.
[image]

If you do not want list blobs, but you want get the blob content. You can do it like below:
[image]

==============================**Update**==============================

Running the logic app, I get the result shown as below screenshot:

[image]

I created three folders `20200101`, `20200202`, `20200303` under `/mycontainer/Invoice` in my blob storage. The content of three csv file are `111,111`, `222,222`, `333,333`. The logic app response the third csv file content `333,333`.

=============================**Update 2**=============================

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hey @Hury, thanks for your response! 
Is this approach tested ?

Comment: @SD4 Of course. I test it in my side, it works fine.

Comment: @SD4 I updated my answer with the running result of the logic app.

Comment: Great @Hury! I'll try this out now. Could you also please share a screenshot of your entire workflow right from the action trigger? Just want to check with mine.

Comment: Also @Hury, if my folder gets saved as 20201001-20201031 & 20201101-20201130 (Format of months, start date to end date), how can I set the expression for this. Any idea?

Comment: Hi @SD4 I provided the entire logic app in my answer under "Update 2". Please check. And I will try to implement your latest requirement.

Comment: Yes thanks so much! 
That would be of great help @Hury. Thanks!

Comment: @SD4 For your latest requirement, if you saved the folder as `20201001-20201031`. You just need to change the expression of "Set variable" for `numberFormatOfName` from `int(replace(items('For_each')?['Name'], '/', ''))` to `int(substring(variables('name'), 0, 8))`.

Comment: I got the following error when I replaced with new expression -> 

"Failed to save logic app <logicapp_name>. The inputs of workflow run action 'Set_variable' of type 'SetVariable' are not valid. The variable 'name' must be initialized before it can be used inside action 'Set_variable'."

Comment: @SD4 Sorry, the expression I provided above is incorrect, I use it in my test. The expression should be `int(substring(items('For_each')?['Name'], 0, 8))`.

Comment: Thanks for the correction friend! Although, now the output gives me the error stating that " mycontainer/invoice/20201001 cannot be found ". Where actually my folder in the container is named "20201001-20201031"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223518/discussion-between-hury-shen-and-sd4).